# Can ediff be used to view an existing diff/patch?

Tags: ediff, diff

Given an existing patch (for example, `git show -c > my.diff; emacs my.diff`)

Most of the commands that are part of ediff rely on having both source & destination available, or referencing revisions.

Can `ediff` be used to view a patch? (without having to have the source/destination files locally).

---

To give some context, I'm curious about using ediff as an alternative to delta which can display side-by-side view from a single diff file (without the source files being stored locally).

Screenshot of delta on the right.

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what ediff would bring here. Which commands are you interested in?

Comment: Yeah, don't think you need ediff at all - just load the patch file into Emacs and run M-x diff-mode.  That should get you syntax highlighting and keyboard shortcuts for navigating the patch.

Comment: @rpluim side-by-side view with syntax highlighting.

Comment: The `ediff-patch-file` command sounds similar to what you want, but it will patch the target file or files before starting the ediff session.  It'll save the original file, and if it's version controlled you can always revert of course, but from the sound of it you don't want the original file(s) modified?

Comment: This sounds like it needs the original file though. Edited the Q to add some context.